# How can Visual Studio 2022 still build my .NET 7 targeted projects, when .NET 7 SDK is not installed anymore on my developer machine?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, .net-7.0, .net-8.0

I have a solution with many projects all with

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
```

I've just upgraded my Visual Studio 2022 to Version 17.8.0, then checked for if the new .NET 8 SDK is installed with this upgrade or not:

```
c:\>dotnet --list-sdks                                                                     
6.0.125 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]                                                                                                                              
8.0.100 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

The output shows, that .NET 7 SDK is not installed anymore, so I opened and rebuilt all my projects, what was a success with no warnings, and checked the output, yes the new build output is there in the net7.0 subfolder.

How can Visual Studio 2022 still build my .NET 7 targeted projects, when .NET 7 SDK is not installed anymore on my developer machine?
What am I missing?

Comment: The SDK consists of two major sub-components, the build tools (compiler, msbuild, etc) and the reference assemblies.  You still have the latter, that's all the compiler needs to target a specific .net version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Select the .NET version to use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection#the-sdk-uses-the-latest-installed-version) doc:

> ##### The SDK uses the latest installed version
>
> SDK commands include `dotnet new` and `dotnet run`. The .NET CLI must choose an SDK version for every dotnet command. It uses the latest SDK installed on the machine by default, even if:
>
> - The project targets an earlier version of the .NET runtime.
> - The latest version of the .NET SDK is a preview version.

Newer SDKs can build projects with older TFMs ([target framework moniker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks)) at least to some versions earlier (maybe there is a limit for backwards compatibility), so actually you need .NET 7 or later to build project targeting `net7.0`.

And this behavior is supported by VS.

Comment: So, in the scenario of the questioner, if .NET 8 SDK is removed, the Visual Studio project with target .NET 7 will no longer build?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why .NET 7.0 got uninstalled, but you can have as many SDK versions installed in parallel as you wish (including multiple versions of the same main version, even though I don't recommend this).

Just go to https://aka.ms/dotnet-download and download and install the version you need.